# BIRT Scripted data source : undefined variable

Tags: dataset, datasource, birt

I'm facing this error when trying to generated `BIRT` report based on scripted data source :

```
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "count" n'est pas défini (/report/data-sets/script-data-set[@id="248"]/method[@name="fetch"]#1)
```

> In English : undefined variable "count"

I didn't find sufficient documentation about this case.

These are the Java classes and the report model.

Thank you for help.

AppDS (Datasource class) :

```
package projds;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AppDS {

    public  List<Entity> getEntities() {
        List<Entity> t = new ArrayList<Entity>();
        t.add(new Entity("A1"));
        t.add(new Entity("A2"));
        t.add(new Entity("A3"));
        t.add(new Entity("A4"));
        return t;
    }

}
```

Entity class :

```
package projds;

public class Entity {

    String name;

    public Entity() {
        super();
    }

    public Entity(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Report model :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.23" id="1">
    <property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 4.6.0.v201606072122</property>
    <property name="units">in</property>
    <property name="iconFile">/templates/first_report.gif</property>
    <property name="bidiLayoutOrientation">ltr</property>
    <property name="imageDPI">96</property>
    <data-sources>
        <script-data-source name="dsrc1" id="247"/>
    </data-sources>
    <data-sets>
        <script-data-set name="dset1" id="248">
            <list-property name="resultSetHints">
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">0</property>
                    <property name="name">colName</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <list-property name="columnHints">
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">colName</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">The Name</text-property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <structure name="cachedMetaData">
                <list-property name="resultSet">
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">1</property>
                        <property name="name">colName</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    </structure>
                </list-property>
            </structure>
            <property name="dataSource">dsrc1</property>
            <method name="open"><![CDATA[importPackage(Packages.projds);

var dummyObject = new Object();



var gsh = new AppDS();

var data = gsh.getEntities();

var count = 0;]]></method>
            <method name="fetch"><![CDATA[if(count < data.size()) {
       row["colName"] = data.get(count).getName();
       count++;
       return true;
}

return false;]]></method>
            <method name="close"><![CDATA[dummyObject = null;

gsh = null;

data = null;

var count = 0;]]></method>
        </script-data-set>
    </data-sets>
    <styles>
        <style name="report" id="110">
            <property name="fontFamily">sans-serif</property>
            <property name="fontSize">10pt</property>
        </style>
    </styles>
    <page-setup>
        <simple-master-page name="Simple MasterPage" id="2">
            <page-footer>
                <text id="3">
                    <property name="contentType">html</property>
                    <text-property name="content"><![CDATA[<value-of>new Date()</value-of>]]></text-property>
                </text>
            </page-footer>
        </simple-master-page>
    </page-setup>
    <body>
        <label id="245">
            <property name="fontFamily">sans-serif</property>
            <property name="fontSize">x-large</property>
            <property name="fontWeight">bold</property>
            <property name="textAlign">center</property>
            <text-property name="text">Customer Listing</text-property>
        </label>
        <table id="325">
            <property name="dataSet">dset1</property>
            <list-property name="boundDataColumns">
                <structure>
                    <property name="name">colName</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">The Name</text-property>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["colName"]</expression>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <column id="334"/>
            <header>
                <row id="326">
                    <cell id="327">
                        <label id="328">
                            <text-property name="text">The Name</text-property>
                        </label>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </header>
            <detail>
                <row id="329">
                    <cell id="330">
                        <data id="331">
                            <property name="resultSetColumn">colName</property>
                        </data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </detail>
            <footer>
                <row id="332">
                    <cell id="333"/>
                </row>
            </footer>
        </table>
    </body>
    <property name="pageVariables">
        <variable-element name="data">
            <property name="type">report</property>
        </variable-element>
    </property>
</report>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the same variable in different method scopes. You have methods defined in the `fetch`, `open` and `close` phase. All three are using a variable called `count`. The visibilty of that variable is fixed to the specific phase. You **cannot** access local variables from `fetch` in `open`, etc. As you are using `count` in `fetch`, where it was not defined, an error raises.

To implement your counter you can, for instance, define a global variable with `reportContext.setGlobalVariable(key, value)` as described here: [Eclipse Forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/309602/).

Moreover, for your particular case, keep in mind, that you do not need to count rows in BIRT:

1. There is a variable available on each column binding called `row.__rownum` that delivers the current row index.
2. If you just need the total number of rows or entries, simply add a computed column with a `count` statement to your dataset.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty fix would be removing in open the var keyword from variables that you want to be seen in global scope. Currently they are bound to the scope of a function - `open()` - and are thus not visible for a different function, `fetch()`. Here is a code snippet to play with:

```
function open(){
  test = '42'
}

function fetch(){
  console.log(test)
}
open()
fetch()
```

[See it on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wiyuyusati/embed?js,console,output)

As noted, this is a dirty fix.

> You can declare a variable without using the var keyword and assign a value to it. This is known as an implicit declaration, and it is not recommended. An implicit declaration gives the variable global scope. When you declare a variable at the procedure level, though, you typically do not want it to have global scope. To avoid giving the variable global scope, you must use the var keyword in your variable declaration.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/var-statement-javascript

The lack of introductory documentation on the topic is quite frustrating indeed.